# Python - How to create an Excel Calculated Field without modifying original source of Data

Tags: python, excel

I have 2 tables on Excel:

[image: tables].

I've created an excel Pivot Table using Python but I could not find a **simple** way to create a calculated field inside it (like I would do with VB) which matches Region from left table and Region from right table.

So I did this, using the module win32com.client:

First, stored the content of the tables in two lists : myTable and myRates.

Then, **added a new column to the original left table** where I calculated `CA * (1 + rate)`. The code here:

```
calField = [['CA Bonifié']] #first element as a title for the new column :
for a, testMyTable in enumerate(myTable):
    for b, testMyRates in enumerate(myRates):
        if a >0 and b > 0:
            if testMyTable[0] == testMyRates[0]:
                calField.append( [ testMyTable[ len(testMyTable)-1 ] * ( 1+testMyRates[1] ) ] )

for i, testDataRow in enumerate(calField):
    for j, testDataItem in enumerate(testDataRow):
        Sheet1.Cells(i+1,len(testMyTable)+1).Value = testDataItem
```

What it does in the sheet "source":

[image: alteration]

What it does in the created sheet "TCD":

[image: expected result]

Result is ok but I don't like this method as it alterates the original table. So I'm looking a simplest method to do that.

Thanks in advance for your help

PS : The whole code below. May it help.

```
import win32com.client
Excel   = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

win32c = win32com.client.constants

Excel.Visible = True

wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open('C:/Users/Documents/Python/classeur.xlsx')

Sheet1 = wb.Worksheets('Source')

def getContiguousRange(fichier, sheet, row, col):

    bottom = row
    while sheet.Cells(bottom + 1, col).Value not in [None, '']:
        bottom = bottom + 1

    right = col
    while sheet.Cells(row, right + 1).Value not in [None, '']:
        right = right + 1

    return sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(row, col), sheet.Cells(bottom, right)).Value

myTable = getContiguousRange(fichier = wb, sheet = Sheet1, row = 1, col = 1)
myRates =   getContiguousRange(fichier = wb, sheet = Sheet1, row = 1, col = 8)

calField = [['CA Bonifié']]
for a, testMyTable in enumerate(myTable):
    for b, testMyRates in enumerate(myRates):
        if a >0 and b > 0:
            if testMyTable[0] == testMyRates[0]:
                calField.append( [ testMyTable[ len(testMyTable)-1 ] * ( 1+testMyRates[1] ) ] )

for i, testDataRow in enumerate(calField):
    for j, testDataItem in enumerate(testDataRow):
        Sheet1.Cells(i+1,len(testMyTable)+1).Value = testDataItem

cl1 = Sheet1.Cells(1,1)
cl2 = Sheet1.Cells(len(myTable),len(myTable[0])+1)

pivotSourceRange = Sheet1.Range(cl1,cl2)
pivotSourceRange.Select() 

Sheet2 = wb.Sheets.Add (After=wb.Sheets (1))
Sheet2.Name = 'TCD'

cl3=Sheet2.Cells(4,1)
pivotTargetRange=  Sheet2.Range(cl3,cl3)
pivotTableName = 'tableauCroisé'

pivotCache = wb.PivotCaches().Create(SourceType=win32c.xlDatabase, SourceData=pivotSourceRange, Version=win32c.xlPivotTableVersion14)

pivotTable = pivotCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination=pivotTargetRange, TableName=pivotTableName, DefaultVersion=win32c.xlPivotTableVersion14)

pivotTable.PivotFields('Service').Orientation = win32c.xlRowField
pivotTable.PivotFields('Service').Position = 1
pivotTable.PivotFields('Region').Orientation = win32c.xlPageField
pivotTable.PivotFields('Region').Position = 1
pivotTable.PivotFields('Region').CurrentPage = 'IDF'

dataField = pivotTable.AddDataField(pivotTable.PivotFields('CA'))
dataField.NumberFormat = '# ### €'

calculField = pivotTable.AddDataField(pivotTable.PivotFields('CA Bonifié'))
calculField.NumberFormat = '# ### €'

# wb.SaveCopyAs('C:/Users/Documents/Python/tcd.xlsx') 
# wb.Close(True)
# Excel.Application.Quit()
```

Comment: Do you want to add Formula `Cell.values`?

Comment: Hi @stovfl, what I want is to do the calculation directly in the pivot table. so I don't have to add a column in the original data table

Comment: _"don't have to add a column"_, make no sense to me? [Edit] your Question and show Picture of the expected Output

Comment: _"calculated field"_ are called **Formula Cell.value**. You want a Formula references Sheet.source.CA, Sheet.source.Tax, with Lookup Table source.Region == source.Tax.Region. You didn't mention which Python `xlsx` Module you want to use? Do you have already such a _calculated field_ Formula from Excel or VB, if so [Edit] your Question an show it.

Comment: wouldn't this be easiest to add during the creation of the table? If you can show how you did it there it might be easy

Comment: @stovfl I unfortunately don't have the VB code. I use win32com.client module. Thanks again

Comment: `win32com.client module` is nothing I'm aware of able to alter `xmls` Files? [Edit] your Question and show your `import` Statements and how you `instantiated myTable`.

Comment: @stovfl it's not xmls but xlsx. I'll put the whole code. it will make things easier

Answer (score 0):

> **Note**: I'm using `Sheet1` as the Image show all relevant indices and its easier to verify.
>   You can move the `Formula` to the PivotTabel at a later Step, once verified.

1. STEP Replace Column `E` with the `Formula =VLOOKUP`
   Reference: [how-to-use-vlookup-match](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/how-to-use-vlookup-match/)

   Replace the following in your Code:

   ```
   for row, testDataRow in enumerate(calField, 2):
       #Sheet1.Cells(i+1,len(testMyTable)+1).Value = testDataItem
       Sheet1.Cells(row, 5).Formula = '=VLOOKUP(A{}, H1:I5, MATCH(H1,H1:I1))'.format(row)
   ```

   The Result should show the matching `Taux`!
   Come back and confirm Results are OK!
2. STEP Compute `Taux`